# how to get z-index with positioning to work on hover

Tags: z-index

I have set z-index set with position:absolute on some elements but when I hover over one element, the other one sits on top of it, despite it having a lower z-index. You can see this at

http://governapps.com/temp/testhover.html

Any ideas on how to get the "category" element to appear ABOVE the "menu items" on hover?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For one you could place your category in its own element then give it a higher z-index with a position absolute as well.

Alternatively, you could just properly margin your floating element so it doesn't conceal the category.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You say:</strike>

> the other one sits on top of it, despite it having a lower z-index

But that's not (really) the case.

The 'sub-categories' are also in that element. So they can never be under the element in which they are.

Move the 'sub-categories' outside the element and it should work.

Would it be possible to make the category element also `position: absolute;`?

It has to do with `relative` vs `absolute` positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/B8Cx7/